# (vhdl) std_logic_vector value

Tags: vhdl

I have a project with the following 3 files, and I am getting this error in the CA file:

```
Line 65: Type error near state_int ; current type std_logic_vector; expected type std_logic
ERROR:HDLCompiler:854 - "" Line 40: Unit  ignored due to previous errors.
```

---

CA FILE

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity CA is

    port(clk,rst:in std_logic;
             state:out std_logic_vector(0 to 8)
            );

end CA;

architecture Behavioral of CA is

    Component cell
        port(L,R,clk,rst:in std_logic;
                 state:out std_logic
            );
    end component;

    Component cellm
        port(L,R,clk,rst:in std_logic;
                 state:out std_logic
            );
    end component;

    signal state_int:std_logic_vector(0 to 8);

begin


    state <= state_int; 
    U_cell0:cell

    port map(clk => clk,
                rst =>rst,
                L => '0',
                R => state_int,
                state => state_int(0)
                );


end Behavioral;
```

---

CELL FILE

```
entity cell is

    port(L,R,clk,rst:in std_logic;
                 state:out std_logic
            );

end cell;

architecture Behavioral of cell is

signal state_pr,state_nx:std_logic;

begin

    state_nx <= ((not L) and R and state_pr) or (L and (not R));

    Process(clk,rst)
    Begin
        if rst = '0' then
            state_pr <= '0';    
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            state_pr <= state_nx;
        end if;
    end process;    

end Behavioral;
```

---

CELLM FILE

```
entity cellm is

    port(L,R,clk,rst:in std_logic;
                 state:out std_logic
            );

end cellm;

architecture Behavioral of cellm is

    signal state_pr,state_nx:std_logic;

begin

    state_nx <= ((not L) and R and state_pr) or (L and (not R));

    Process(clk,rst)
    Begin
        if rst = '0' then
            state_pr <= '1';    
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            state_pr <= state_nx;
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's been a while since I did VHDL, but it seems that you are trying to connect a `std_logic_vector` signal and a `std_logic` port. This will, obviously, not work due to mismatch (single vs multi-lane).

Comment: You mapped R (std_logic) to state_int (std_logic_vector) in the component U_cell0: `R => state_int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have three problems in your design. The first two problems were mentioned in the comments:

1. you are trying to connect a std_logic_vector signal **state_int** and a std_logic port **R**. This will, obviously, not work due to mismatch (single vs multi-lane)
2. In the next line you are also trying to connect a std_logic_vector signal **state** and a std_logic port **state_int(0)**.
3. You also have another problem in you cell entity. The **state** output is never assigned to anything. So there will be no actual output from the cell entity. You might eventually get a warning from the compiler about this.

Comment: Please make your answer self-contained. Giving credit is always polite, but include the relevant information in your answer, because comments might vanish.

Comment: 1. `R` and `state_int` are different *types* and cannot be associated. Associate  input `R` with indexed name `state_int(0)`? 2. Connecting a formal `state` to an actual that is an indexed named (`state_int(0)`) is legal. The base type of the element type of std_logic_vector is the same as the base type of std_logic (std_ulogic or std_logic dependent on -2008 or earlier).  3. This code appears unfinished. `U_cell0` output `state` is associated with `state_int(0)` which could be assigned to an element of output port `state`..